# Removing from vowels from a string

Tags: python

Here is the code I have:

```
import string # to import the alphabet <-'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
alpha = string.lowercase
vowels = "aeiou"
alpha = alpha.strip(vowels)
sentence = "methinks it is like a weasel"
words = sentence.split(" ")
characters = list(sentence)

words
characters
alpha
vowels
```

when I print I get this:

```
['methinks', 'it', 'is', 'like', 'a', 'weasel']

['m', 'e', 't', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'k', 's', ' ', 'i', 't', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'l', 'i', 'k', 'e', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'w', 'e', 'a', 's', 'e', 'l']

'bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
'aeiou'
```

I would like it to remove all vowels from the alphabet, but thus far it is only removing the a (the leading coefficient).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[character for character in sentence if character not in vowels] # returns list
```

This list comprehension should do the trick for you.

The way it works is that it takes advantage of the fact that `vowels` and `sentences` are *iterables*: you can define a for-loop over them, so to speak. Specifically, it pulls every character in `sentence`, checks if that same character does not appear in `vowels`, and only then does it insert it into a list.

If you want a string at the end, simply use `join`:

```
''.join([character for character in sentence if character not in vowels]) # returns string without vowels
```

Comment: what if I made vowels into a list?

Comment: It'll still work even then. Lists, like strings, are iterable and support lookup.

Comment: thank you for your help!

Comment: @mathguy84 Upvote + selected answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a sample code, hope it helps.

```
words = ['Ahmad Siavashi', 'Mohammad Siavashi']
print [''.join([c for c in w if c not in 'aeoui']) for w in words]
```

Output:

```
['Ahmd Svsh', 'Mhmmd Svsh']
```

and if you only want for one string, use:

```
print ''.join([c for c in "methinks it is like a weasel" if c not in 'aeoui'])
```